# What does the command line arguments for PM2 startup mean precisely

Tags: pm2

I am a little confused about start up scripts and the command line options.  I am building a small raspberry pi based server for my node applications.  In order to provide maximum protection against power failures and flash write corruption, the root file system is read only, and that embraces the home directory of my main user, were the production versions of my apps (two of them) are stored.  Because the .pm2 directory here is no good for logs etc I currently set PM2_HOME environment variable to a place in /var (which has 512kb unused space around it to ensure writes to i.  The eco-system.json file reads this environment variable also to determine where to place its logs.

In case I need to, I also have a secondary user with a read write home directory in another (protected by buffer space around it) partition. This contains development versions of my application code which because of the convenience of setting environments up etc I also want to monitor with PM2. If I need to investigate a problem I can log in to that user and run and test the application there.

Since this is a headless box, and with watchdog and kernel panic restarts built in, I want pm2 to start during boot and at minimum restart the two production apps.  Ideally it should also starts the two development versions of the app also but I can live without that if its impossible.

I can switch the read only root partition to read/write - indeed it does so automatically when I ssh into my production user account. It switches back to read only automatically when I log out.

So I went to this account to try and create a startup script.  It then said (unsurprisingly) that I had to run a sudo command like so:-

```
sudo su -c "env PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin pm2 startup ubuntu -u pi --hp /home/pi"
```

The key issue for me here is the --hp switch.  I went searching for some clue as to what it means.  Its clearly a home directory, but it doesn't match PM2_HOME - which is set to /var/pas in my case to take it out of the read only area.  I don't want to try and and spray my home directory with files that shouldn't be there.  So am asking for some guidance here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out by experiment what it does with an "ubuntu" start up script.  It uses it to set PM2_HOME in the script by appending "/.pm2" to it.

However there is nothing stopping you editing the script once it has created it and setting PM2_HOME to whatever you want.

So effectively its a helper for the script, but only that and nothing more special.